# Pandas assign to slice

Tags: python, pandas

I have some old python code that I have to transition from pandas 0.10 to 0.15 big jump.   The old python code has multiple assignments to slices using the following structure:

```
condition = a['Column'] != 'option' #  with lots of complex logic
df.ColumnX[condition] = new_value
```

I know this is a an assigning to a slice.   In pandas 10 this worked, as documented in various pandas upgrades it does not work.    without having to refactor the code totally is the a way of changing line 2 so that it can still use the loc method while still using the condition as defined on line 1.

I have tried:

```
df.loc[:,condition] = 'new_val'
```

but I get

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided

can anybody suggest a syntax that would (preferably backward compatible to pandas 0.10 that would provide quick fix without re-factoring dozens of complex selections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative for `df.ColumnX[condition] = new_value` is:

```
df.loc[condition, 'ColumnX'] = new_value
```

So you put the `condition` in the wrong place, trying to slice the columns instead of the rows, hence the error message that it is unalignable.